# Which is more efficient in Stan?

Tags: r, stan

Is it more efficient to declare a transformed parameter in the transformed parameters block or in the model block if I do not require the transformed parameter to be returned in the output.

For example

```
data {
  real<lower=0> tt[N]; 
  ...
}
parameters {
  real <lower = 0> mu;
  real <lower = 0> eta;
  ...
}
transformed parameters{
  real Mu[N];
  for(i in 1:N){
    Mu[i] = eta + mu*log(tt[i]);
  }
  ...
}
```

Compared to

```
data {
  real<lower=0> tt[N]; 
  ...
}
parameters {
  real <lower = 0> mu;
  real <lower = 0> eta;
  ...
}
model{
  real Mu[N];
  for(i in 1:N){
    Mu[i] = eta + mu*log(tt[i]);
  }
  ...
}
```

Does it take more run time in order to store all of the values of Mu in the first block of code (when I declare Mu in the transformed parameter block)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The efficiency (with respect to time) is essentially the same. If you declare something in the `transformed parameters` blocks it takes a usually small amount of time to validate the constraints that you declare on each transformed parameter. Basically the only situation in which the constraint-checking is noticeable is when you are forming a correlation matrix or covariance matrix, which is has to factor in order to verify that it is positive definite. In the example you gave, `Mu` is unconstrained so there is nothing to check. If you are not interested in the intermediate parameters, it makes sense to declare them in the `model` block, in which case you will save some RAM (in RStan or PyStan) by not storing all of them and perhaps a little bit of time by avoiding the corresponding I / O.

Comment: In my dummy example, I actually omitted some code which created a covariance matrix in the transformed parameter block. I noticed that this increased my runtime substantially compared to when I created it in the model block.

Comment: If you are sure that the covariance matrix is positive definite by construction, then I would declare that in the model block.